# If a staff member has maxed out their relevant stats is there a reason to assign later points?

Tags: fiz

I have a character assigned to Mash/Boil who has maxed out his Intelligence, Dexterity and Craft values.  However, he is still levelling up, and has already earned at least one extra stat point.

Is there a reason to assign said stat point to Patience?  It's not the stat he's using, and it will increase the cost of his monthly wage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if he has a passive so good that being able to move him from Mash/Boil to Cleaning or Fermenting would allow you to bring in another employee with *another* highly desirable passive and not enough patience to be useful.

In other words, it gives you the flexibility to rearrange your brewing process. If you place no value on that flexibility, there is no advantage to leveling up.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer, but read something from the dev that made me realize the accepted answer is actually wrong.

http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=212350&page=13

Post by seandanger:

> Each time an Employee successfully completes an attempt to add Quality, they then add a certain amount of Quality, which is a random number between a range of 2 values. These 2 values are also selected by a table, based on the sum of Intelligence, Dexterity, and Patience, divided by 3, and rounded up.

though only the relevant stats determine their chance to add quality at their station, the amount of quality is determined by the average of all 3 attributes.

A 10 10 1 10 character will add less quality than a 10 10 10 10 character.